# What am I supposed to with a completed review that I was prompted to visit by an email?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, notifications

I just got an e-mail that I have an inbox item. The interface gives me the impression that I should do something. How can I approve the review? I only see a button for a reject.

[image]

Comment: i think that's a bug because on the left it says it was already approved and i don't recall Post Owners being about to reject suggested edits after the community has approved them

Comment: It was already reviewed and approved, but you as the original author can override and reject the edit. This is [a fairly new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/13531) and I can see how it would be confusing.

Comment: @Memor-X OPs can override the community's decision since it was implemented last week or so.

Comment: @Floern that would probably explains why i initially thought it to be a bug

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get email notifications for things that have been sitting around in your inbox for a long time. In the case of suggested edits, leaving it sit around can result in it already having been handled by the time you look at it, which is the case here. If you look at the top left of that box, you'll see that it was already approved 14 hours ago by the two users listed below.

If you don't agree with the edit, you *can* override that approval and reject the edit, reverting the post to its previous form. Otherwise, there is nothing for you to do other than be aware that your post was changed.

Comment: Maybe a disabled *Aprove* Button, which shows on hover, it is already approved would be more clear?

Comment: @Christian We're discussing how it could be improved [on another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296166/user-experience-of-overriding-communitys-decision-on-suggested-edit).